# How do I check if my (x,y) are gaussian sampled?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to get (x,y) of 100 particles (x and y being initial conditions) sampled from a 2D gaussian where the 2-D gaussian is a product of two 1-D Gaussians so that (x,y) corresponds to a point on the surface of a 3D gaussian figure.

I did the following for that:

```
"r"
 mu=np.random.uniform(0,1,10000)
 r=[sqrt(-2*log(1-i)) for i in mu]
 "theta"
 eta=np.random.uniform(0,1,10000)
 theta=2*pi*eta;
 cuz=[cos(i) for i in theta]
 suz=[sin(i) for i in theta]
 "initial conditions"
 Zinitial=[a*b for a,b in zip(r,cuz)];
 Pinitial=[a*b for a,b in zip(r,suz)];
```

I now want to confirm whether these data points actually are gaussian sampled by drawing contour or 3-d plot.

How can I do that?

Now consider the following code:
Consider the following code:

```
def gauss2d(mu,sigma):
    x=gauss(mu,sigma);
    y=gauss(mu,sigma);
 return(x,y)
ic=[];
for i in range(50):
    ic.append(gauss2d(0,1))
    x=[x[0] for x in ic];
t=np.linspace(-2,2,50)
plt.plot(x,t)
```

This is what I get.
[image]

Why doesn't it look like a gaussian curve?

My plots of this and the one I did with a different method match but both don't look like a gaussian but the plot like above.

Comment: Why would you need to check them if you sampled them from a 2D Gaussian?

Comment: Because I have done the sampling from a method different from the in-built command like I showed here. I want to confirm that those points are actually gaussian sampled. So I was planning to see how the plot looks for the in-built command and then compare it with that different method. I'll probably edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: There's no binary test for that. You can sample from both and compare the moments (mean, variance, skew, kurtosis) or look at the probability of the samples given the distribution (using the pdf). But because of the randomness involved, there's just no way to know for sure. Even if you sample from a normal distribution (and you know it), your samples COULD look very non-normel, even though that's unlikely.

Comment: Can you please look at the following question of mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask         which I think would answer this one too because I could simply check for a gaussian curve in my methods but instead I get a fuzzy graph for both?

Comment: You didn't link a question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: That's the same link, it doesn't link to a specific question.

Comment: Shoot I  think the other question is not posted yet. I can only post after 90 mins. Should I edit this one to that?

Comment: If you want to see how your points are distributed, you need to plot their histogram (which is roughly their distribution), not plot the points as a function of time, or whatever variables that quantify the number of points sampled.

Comment: You're plotting a sorted array (`t`) vs. a random array (`x`). Why should this look like a gaussian distribution?

Comment: LukasNeugebauer Oh Thank you. It's clear now. I was of the impression that since the values are taken from a Gaussian distribution they would look like a gaussian. I would need to plot the histogram as Liris mentioned.

Comment: @LukasNeugebauer
 Then I can probably just look at the histogram distribution of the points I generated and if it's correct it should give the gaussian like distribution right?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this example: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_hist.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-hist-py

Comment: I think so. But that's just the 1-D version then. You can use `seaborn.kdeplot` if you want the 2D version.